# unable to validate span radio buttons both in HTML5, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, html-table

HTML

```
<table class="tbl" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">
     <tr>
     <td style="color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); font-weight:300">Gender</td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
    <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="gender" value="male" required/>
    <label for="radio01"><span></span>Male</label>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="gender" value="female" required/>
    <label for="radio02"><span></span>Female</label>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>`
```

CSS

```
input[type="radio"] {
        display:none;
    }

    input[type="radio"] + label {
        color: #000;
        font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size:16px;
        color: #000;
        padding-right:50px;
    }

    input[type="radio"] + label span {
        display:inline-block;
        width:5px;
        height:10px;
        margin:-3px 8px 0 0;
        vertical-align:middle;
        cursor:pointer;
        -moz-border-radius:  50%;
        border-radius:  50%;
        background-color:#aaa;
    }

    input[type="radio"]:checked + label span{
         background-color:#00695c;
    }

    input[type="radio"] + label span,
    input[type="radio"]:checked + label span {
      -webkit-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
      -o-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
      -moz-transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
      transition:background-color 0.4s linear;
    }
```

JQuery function

```
  $(function() {
     $("form[name='userDetailsForm']").validate({
         rules: {
             gender: {
                 required: true
             }
         },
         messages: {
             gender: {
                 required: "Please specify your gender"
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

NOTE : There are no errors in the script. I am able to validate the other fields that i'm using currently in my form except for the radio buttons. I have another 2 set of similar radio buttons with the same problem. I expect these radio buttons atleast to work for "required" which is a HTML5 validation.

Comment: leave html5 validation for required, check by removing required attribute of that element and check whether its validating through jqueryvalidation plugin

Comment: It doesnt works even after removing 'required'

Comment: https://jqueryvalidation.org/required-method/ Check sample radio button validation here, its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you comment these lines of code

`input[type="radio"] { display:none;}`

and validate the form

Comment: This works! and instead of using `input[type="radio"] { display:none;}` I did use `input[type="radio"] { visibility:hidden;}` to solve my problem. Cheers!

Comment: jQuery error is displayed on 1st option of the radio button. (Ex: In "male td it says "please specify the gender" and the radio is not displayed for male after showing error)

Comment: I want it at the end of corresponding tr. Tried many stuffs but nothing worked. I suspect something wrong with CSS>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this:

```
`input[type="radio"] { display:none;}`
```

This can be used which can be validated later:

```
`input[type="radio"] { visibility:hidden;}`
```